# Как проверить, приходит ли ответ на запрос в формате JSON

Tags: javascript

Как проверить, что при Ajax-запросе в `data` приходит JSON, а не что-то иное?

Comment: откуда приходит?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman аякс -> пост

Comment: пожалуйста добавьте код запроса.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman причем тут запрос. Есть переменная в которой или json или бред с html так вот нужно проверить что там именно json и выполнить определенные действия.

Comment: а если на *сервере* реализовать что метод будет возвращать `json` в случае успеха или же кидать исключение(или же возвращать необходимый статус код(400)) и на клиенте потом проверять результат запроса например через `.then(successCallback, errorCalback)`?

Comment: а зачем проверять?

Comment: @Grundy легких путей не ищем :))) Долго объяснять, в общем для совсем чайников это нужно :)))

Comment: Не, от цели же может зависеть. А также от того, почему сервер вообще может прислать не то, что попросили. То есть нет смысла разбирать json, только для того, чтобы узнать что действительно пришел json.

Comment: @Grundy в ответе нужно и то и то. Просто в зависимости что пришло делать нужные действия.    Таким образом запрос на сервер один.

Comment: @wwwplaton, но ты же знаешь на какой адрес ты делаешь запрос, неужели сервер под одному и тому же запросу может вернуть разные результаты?

Comment: @Grundy да я и не такое видел, в моей практике случается разное. И тут не исключение. Последний раз попал в руки код который передает в класс различные ссылки с титлами в одной строке разделяя ссылку и титлы & я думаю вы догадались почему такой код ломался :)))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробовать сделать `JSON.parse`, завернутый в try-catch:

```
var isJson = true;
try {
    JSON.parse(data);
} catch(e) {
    isJson = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Привет,

В хедере респонса контентного типа должен хранится формат респонса
например используя библиотеку jQuery такое решение подойдет:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://******",
    data: {*****},
    headers: {*****},
    success: function (dt, status, request) {
        var isJson = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type') == 'application/json';
    }
});
```

Comment: content-type не обязан совпадать с реальным содержимым

Comment: @Grundy да, стоит упомянуть, если сервис адекватный

Comment: Если сервис адекватный, то у него в принципе вряд ли окажется не json, когда ожидается json

Comment: Согласен,есть в этом смысл